# Finding color on flex page

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications

I want to find some color on flex page exists or not?
For example

```
if(red color exists on page){
   Alert.show("red exixts");
}else{
   Alert.show("red does not exists");
}
```

so before writing this if else block,i need to find the red color(any where on flex page)

Note:- My page do not hav any images.with images i m getting the color.My page has a canvas and hboxes and diff texts with diff colors.

Done with bitmap,bitmap data.....NO LUCK :(  Please help me wit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you start iterating over all the children objects of the application, get the colour property, using getStyle("propertyname"), and you will find the colour of all possible objects.This is much better than rendering the whole app, into a bitmap and then testing for each pixel.

Answer (score 2):

Draw your page (application?) into bitmap. Then analyze each pixel (may take time). What red do you need? If you accept not only pure red (0xFF0000), define minimum level for red channel and maximum for other channels. As soon as "red" pixel is found, quit checking.